# Use same view from different controls?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a `Member` and `Staff` controllers and these both controls need to use common code view for `Search` and `SearchResults` views. Now these views are in `Member` controllers.

So My question is How can I manage URLs like `Member/Search` and `Staff/Search` 
 and  `Member/SearchResults` and `Staff/SearchResults`? Beacuse I need to protect these urls from security product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep your controller/actions just like you have them, you only need to specify the View that you want to return your search results to.

**Staff Controller**

```
//Get Staff/SearchResults
public ActionResult SearchResults(){
     var model = StuffToGetResults();
     return View("~/Views/Shared/SearchResults", model);
}
```

**Member Controller**

```
//Get Member/SearchResults
public ActionResult SearchResults(){
     var model = StuffToGetResults();
     return View("~/Views/Shared/SearchResults", model);
}
```

This assumes that you have a common View Model that you are returning your results into.  The same can be done with the Search view as well.